# sync on Firefox between Linux Mint and different platforms

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, libreoffice

I use Mozilla Firefox and LibreOffice on several different platforms (Windows 10, Android,etc) and I love them both.

I recently installed Linux Mint and Firefox and LibreOffice of course came with it (YA!!). But the version number supplied by the Software Manager is far older than the one I use on all my other platforms

- Windows: Firefox 42.0
- Linux Mint: Firefox 24.0

I have also noticed this version number problem with LibreOffice.

Because of this I suspect the "sync" operation in Firefox fails to sync things between the Windows platform and Linux.

I know the documentation seems to advise that all software be managed through the software manager.

Is there a fix to sync failure? Should I go to their respective websites and get the latest version or just wait for the package manager to do it one day?

Comment: Did you run an update? I am pretty sure that there is no supported Mint version with Firefox 24. You should add `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question to see how your repositories are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Update Manager in Linux Mint, should be listed under 'System' in your Application Launcher menu. Also, by default linux mint should have added a shield looking icon in the systray that will change icons on the shield depending if you have updates or not. Click this icon if you have it, and then hit 'Install Updates' if there are some in the list. If not hit 'Refresh' and see if that changes the list of available updates.